# How to know if Redux Devtool window is already opened

Tags: redux, redux-devtools, redux-devtools-extension

We have hot reload turned on for our application, at times the statement of opening Redux Devtool gets triggered.  When it happens, the DevTool steals the focus.  This can get annoying when developer is in the middle of writing and saving code, and the action of saving would trigger the build which subsequently opens the Redux DevTool.

I wonder if there is a way to know if the Redux DevTool is already open, so we can open the devtool when necessary.

Below is the source code we use to open Redux Devtool:

```
if (window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__) {
    enhancers.push(window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__.open('panel');
}
```

Comment: "at times the statement of opening Redux Devtool gets triggered" - gets triggered by what? can you share the relevant code?

Comment: @goldylucks I have updated the post with the source code.  Thanks.